# Failed to insert Í¥ into MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm using `mysqlclient` to insert data into MySQL, but I got the following error:

> Incorrect string value: '\xCD\xA5\xCD\xA5\xCD\xA5...' for column
>   'review' at row 1"

My my table has `CHARSET=utf8mb4`, and the `review` column is a `text` field, `utf-8 unicode(utf8mb4)` and `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

And In my code, I have:

```
cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")
```

Any idea why the error happens, thanks.

Comment: python2 or python3? what is the type of the data you are inserting (e.g. bytes, unicode, string)?

Comment: @davejagoda I'm using python3 and it's a string.

Comment: Are you encoding it before inserting it?
```
>>> s='Í¥'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(s)
Í¥
>>> print(s.encode('utf8'))
b'\xc3\x8d\xc2\xa5'
```

Comment: @davejagoda I tried to insert `Í¥` directly, it worked. Then I tired to insert the review which gave me the error, i got a different error saying 'Data too long'. Maybe that's the actual cause. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Fascinating. I assumed it was an encoding problem of some sort based on the output, but maybe it's just echoing back the raw bytes when the insert fails. I wonder if you can write up your answer and accept it?